# Bash Script - Compare Directory Name to String

Tags: bash

I'm using this script to run a command within each subdirectory in the 'sites' directory, EXCLUDING the 'all' subdirectory. However, when I run this, the 'all' subdirectory is still being used, even though I use an if statement to exclude it.

```
for dir in ~/htdocs/drupal/drupal/sites/*
  do
  if [ $dir = "/local/users/drupadm/htdocs/drupal/drupal/all" ]
    then
    continue
  fi
echo $dir
(cd $dir && /opt/webstack/php/5.2/bin/php /local/users/drupadm/drush/drush.php $1)
done
```

Bryan

Comment: Always quote your `"$variables"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You left out the `sites` sub-directory:

```
if [ "$dir" = /local/users/drupadm/htdocs/drupal/drupal/sites/all ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IFS=$'\n'
for dir in `find ~/htdocs/drupal/drupal/sites/ -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name all -printf '%p\n'`
do
    echo $dir
    (cd $dir && /opt/webstack/php/5.2/bin/php /local/users/drupadm/drush/drush.php $1)
done
IFS=' '
```

Exclude that directory in the first place, use [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)!

It's invoked by

```
find dir_name [tests...]
```

Tests used by my command:

```
-maxdepth 1
```

Of immediate children...

```
-type d
```

... find directories ...

```
! -name all
```

... Not named 'all'.

Comment: Don't use find `\`this way\``. Breaks on whitespace in filenames, you know.

Comment: Agree. Recommend `find ... | while read dir; do ...; done` instead.

Comment: The box I'm on runs SunOS and the find command doesn't support the -maxdepth switch...

Comment: 1.)  If whitespace is an issue, you can always set `IFS=$'\n'`, and then use the action `-printf '%p\n'` at the very end of all that 2.)  Emulating max depth it trickier - I'll check the man page and get back.

Comment: @BryanChristopheGreen  Okay, found an (almost) workaround:  This eliminates hidden folders and is a bit messier, but try `find ~/htdocs/drupal/drupal/sites/* -type d ! -name all ! -path */all/* -prune`  The added test is  `! -path ` (path name not like), and I've used an action at the end, which tells you what to do when you get a match, `-prune` means 'stop searching downward'.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan Thanks for the info! I'll give this a go when I'm back in the office tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

Hi you need to do the following

if [ $dir == "/local/users/drupadm/htdocs/drupal/drupal/all" ]

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try quoting the $dir, you will fine directories with spaces in their names kill you.  You may also run scripts with -vx switches on the invocation to see what's read in and what's executed.
bash -vx my script
or
set -vx
whatever.

Comment: Hey ubfan. This should be a comment since it doesn't directly answer the question.